# jQuery to change HTML mark up and run script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just looking for some help to change this HTML markup with jQuery.

1. When this appears:

   ```
   <span class="ScriptWrapper">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span>
   ```

   use jQuery on doc ready to convert it to:

   ```
   <script src="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></script>
   ```
2. Also, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX external script reference to load an embedded widget, will it run/fire after the document has already loaded or does it need to be fired again?

Comment: Thanks. replaceWith won't work with script tags and definitely won't fire after the page has already loaded.

I might need to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

For load any js after window load or dom ready you have to use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
        console.log( data ); // Data returned
        console.log( textStatus ); // Success
        console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
        console.log( "Load was performed." );
    });
})
```

**Note :** to run this code you need to load jquery default

Answer (score 0):

To replace the span tags and replace it with your script tags use,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $( "#accordion" ).hide();
            var pattern = $('.ScriptWrapper').html();
            if(pattern == 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'){
                $("span.ScriptWrapper").replaceWith('<script src="'+pattern+'">');
            $.getScript( "scriptfile.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
                console.log( data ); // Data returned
                console.log( textStatus ); // Success
                console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
                console.log( "Load was performed." );
            });
            }
        })

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<span class="ScriptWrapper">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span>
    <span class="ScriptWrapper">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
            ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
            amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
            odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Invoking another function in the replaced referenced script can be done in that script file

'scriptfile.js' looks similar to the following,

```
$(function () {
    $( "#accordion" ).show();
});
```